# Is it Theoretically Impossible to Demonstrate that Set Theories Are Consistent?

Tags: logic, set-theory, philosophy

I have to present on the main realist and non-realist arguments for/against set theory. According to one of my sources, it remains a matter of debate as to whether any of the set theories' (ZF, NF, etc.) consistency can be provable “since all of them are strong enough to encompass arithmetic.” This is linked to Godel's Theorem. I need to understand what exactly this means as I thought ZF was consistent.

Comment: You prove one set of theorems consistent in terms of another.  This is unavoidable, there is no universal characteristic of consistency.  It's not meaningful to say "X is consistent", but it is meaningful to say "X is no less consistent than Y".

For example, you could create a set of definitions in first order logic.  From those definitions you could show that the propositions of set theory are implied.  This would imply set theory axioms to be no less consistent than first order logic.

Comment: I can't agree that it's "not meaningful to say 'X is consistent'". If X is a recursively enumerable theory (like pretty much all the theories we talk about in this context), "X is consistent" is a statement of first order arithmetic. Would you say that the statement "there are no odd perfect numbers" is meaningless? If "X is consistent" is meaningless, what happens when an inconsistency is discovered? Does it suddenly become meaningful, or does it remain meaningless?

Comment: @bof: It is debatable whether or not there is an absolute context. Yes, in the case of "There are no odd perfect numbers" it is perfectly clear what is the context. But to say that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, in what context? $\sf ZFC$ itself? Then not quite. $\sf ZFC$ with large cardinals? It is true that all of these can be formulated in $\sf PA$ or even weaker theories ($\sf PRA$ should be enough, I believe). But that is an argument closer to formalism, whereas we can think about semantics, and actual models, which requires far more than $\sf PA$.

Comment: @bof: Yes, "there are no odd perfect numbers" is a meaningless statement, if we are not already working in a context where "odd", "perfect", and "number" all have meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, in order to make your question answerable, you have to provide us more information. You are asking whether consistency of set theories are *provable*. First thing you should specify is, *provable in which system*?

For example, you can prove consistency of ZFC, in a stronger system like ZFC+large cardinals, or in Morse-Kelley set theory, but not in ZFC (or in PA) by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

Though, considering that this question came up in a philosophical discussion, I doubt that this answer is what you are looking for. Why would we care if we could prove consistency of, say ZFC, in a system, consistency of which we have more reasons to doubt, if we are to doubt consistency of set theories at all?

Assume, for a moment, that we could prove consistency of ZFC inside ZFC, would this make ZFC a reliable system? If it were inconsistent, it would prove its consistency anyway. So, why would we bother searching for consistency proofs? You can see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38193/interpretation-of-the-second-incompleteness-theorem) for a related discussion.

I think the point is to find a consistency proof in a system which we have no reason to doubt.

For example, unless you are an ultrafinitist, you believe that PA is consistent. This is not because of fancy reasons, like Gentzen's proof, or some stronger theory like ZFC proving consistency of PA. If you believe that the natural numbers, a model of PA, exists, then you believe that PA is consistent. Or a similar example, if you believe in von Neumann's hierarchy of sets up to level $\omega$, that is, $V_{\omega}=\bigcup_{n \in \omega} V_n$ where $V_0=\emptyset$ and $V_{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_n)$, then you believe that ZFC-Axiom of Infinity is consistent. The reason I am giving these examples is that we have *concrete* models and doubting these theories I consider as an extreme form of skepticism.

Therefore, if we could prove consistency of set theories in systems like PA or PRA or even weaker fragments of PA, then we would have no reason to doubt consistency of those set theories since we would know that there would be a number theoretic proof of that no formal contradiction can be derived. However, this cannot be done by Gödel's theorem.

One last remark, eventhough I said you should believe in consistency of PA if you believe in natural numbers, in case you want to see a mathematical argument for consistency of these theories *without* moving to a stronger theory, you should know that both PA and ZFC can prove consistency of all of their finite fragments (for example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482665/consistency-strength-of-pa)). Although we cannot do a compactness-like argument to deduce the whole theory is consistent, it should be convincing enough.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, we have two ways to show consistency of a mathematical theory :

*1)* The "traditional" one : exhibiting a model. See the model of euclidean plane geometry through the real numbers : Descartes' discovery of *analytical geometry*, or the model of non-euclidean geometry into spherical euclidean one.

We may say that this approach gives us a "relative" consistency : non-euclidean geometry is *consistent*, provdied that euclidean one is.

To apply this method to some specific set theory, like $\mathsf {ZFC}$, we have to build a model of it. How ? using a "stronger" set theory.

The result are mathematically interesting but ... **if** we are interested into *ontological* or *epistemological* motivations for a consistency proof (trivially : I'm sure that sets exist ? less tirvially : comparison between realist and non-realist arguments for/against set theory), this kind of result is hardly what we are searching for.

*2)* The method proposed by Hilbert with the so-called [Hilbert's Program](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/) : to formalize the theory we are searching for consistency (i.e.stating axioms and rules of inference, defining in a rigorous way the concept of *derivation* of a formula in the theory) and prove that a *formal* inconsistency (i.e. an expression $\varphi \land \lnot \varphi$, or $0=1$, if the language of arithmetic is available) is *underivable*.

We may say that Hilbert's goal was to attain an "absolute" consistency proof; the "proving tools" available in his meta-mathematics partain the so-called *finitary* arithmetic. They are so "basic" that hardly we can doubt about their soundness.

Unfortunately, this program has been showed to be unattainable (in its original form) by Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem.

For *first-order* $\mathsf {PA}$, Gentzen proved its [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof), with some "proving technique" not formalizable in $\mathsf {PA}$ itself.

Thus, in principle, to apply the "hilbertian" method to prove consistency of some set theory, we have to supply the meta-theory with "appropriated" tools.